# Error installing ggplot2 in RStudio - MacOS

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to express my thanks in advance for your help. I have been attempting to install the package "ggplot2" for two weeks now in RStudio, and cannot figure out my non-zero exit status errors. I have posted the resulting error code at the end of this message. I have successfully installed some packages, but have failed to install ggplot2 and plotly. I have an assignment due using these packages tonight and would greatly appreciate any insight you can give.

```
> install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘rlang’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘scales’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
          binary source needs_compilation
cli        3.2.0  3.4.1              TRUE
rlang      1.0.2  1.0.6              TRUE
lifecycle  1.0.1  1.0.3             FALSE
scales     1.1.1  1.2.1             FALSE
ggplot2    3.3.5  3.3.6             FALSE

Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source packages ‘cli’, ‘rlang’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘scales’, ‘ggplot2’

trying URL 'http://archive.linux.duke.edu/cran/src/contrib/cli_3.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 540044 bytes (527 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 527 KB

trying URL 'http://archive.linux.duke.edu/cran/src/contrib/rlang_1.0.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 742508 bytes (725 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 725 KB

trying URL 'http://archive.linux.duke.edu/cran/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 106854 bytes (104 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 104 KB

trying URL 'http://archive.linux.duke.edu/cran/src/contrib/scales_1.2.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 270609 bytes (264 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 264 KB

trying URL 'http://archive.linux.duke.edu/cran/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.3.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 3061989 bytes (2.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.9 MB

* installing *source* package ‘cli’ ...
** package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘cli’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/cli’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/cli’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘cli’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘rlang’ ...
** package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rlang’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rlang’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘lifecycle’ ...
** package ‘lifecycle’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘lifecycle’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/lifecycle’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘lifecycle’ is not available for package ‘scales’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/scales’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘scales’ is not available for package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/ggplot2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/sr/02bnxzdx0hvcp6c37xfhlf300000gn/T/Rtmpje9xhl/downloaded_packages’
> library(ggplot2)
Error in library(ggplot2) : there is no package called ‘ggplot2’
```

Comment: When you receive the prompt to install the source, just  response with no.  The slight change in the most recent version is not worth the trouble of compiling the source code.

Comment: If you need to install from source, run `xcode-select --install` in a terminal [as described here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a). Otherwise just answer "no" when asked whether to install from source.